# Phoenix IEx.pry not putting a break point in code

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I wanted to debug Controllers in Phoenix the way i used to do with Rails by simply putting `binding.pry` at any place i want to put a break point, So, i tried the same thing with Phoenix using `IEx.pry` like below:-

```
defmodule Rumbl.UserController do
  use Rumbl.Web, :controller
  require IEx

  def index(conn, _params) do
    IEx.pry
    users = Repo.all(Rumbl.User)
    render conn, "index.html", users: users
  end
end
```

But it's not putting any break point instead it's giving this message on console.

`Cannot pry #PID<0.352.0> at web/controllers/users_controller.ex:6. Is an IEx shell running?`

I also, tried running Iex shell by doing `iex -S mix` but problem still continues.  Did, i miss something or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: What error do you get with `iex -S mix`? Did you pass `phoenix.server` as an argument too? Try with `iex -S mix phoenix.server`.

Comment: 1. Stop current server. 2. Start server with `iex -S mix phoenix.server`. Are the results exactly the same?

Comment: ohh So, phoenix server itself has to run from IEx shell. Got it and it worked fine now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even I ran into this issue. Try this

- Stop current server.
- Start server with `iex -S mix phoenix.server`

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is following an old tutorial - following up on coderVishal's answer,

- Stop the running server
- Start the server with `iex -S mix phx.server`